# Lock screen when key pad appears in android

Tags: android, screen, android-keypad

When adding text to `Edittext` in a screen the key pad appears and the screen is pushed up. I want to keep the screen as it is when the key pad appears. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that `EditText` is showing inside `MainActivity` ,

Inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`,

Inside `activity` tag,

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"   //this is what you need to add
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you,

- Use this code in onCreate() method:

  ```
  getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
  ```

**OR**

- Set Window SoftInput Mode property to adjustPan and adjustResize

  ```
  <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"> </activity>
  ```

Comment: what about in fragment

Answer (score 1):

In manifest, you can specif `windowSoftInputMode` for activity or for application. it can be `android:windowSoftInputMode=["stateUnspecified",
                                       "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
                                       "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
                                       "stateAlwaysVisible", "adjustUnspecified",
                                       "adjustResize", "adjustPan"]`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html